# Is there *any* difference between map.updated(k,v) and map + (k,v)? I'm getting a compile error on one but not the other

Tags: scala

I'm new (about a month) to Scala. I just came across a type-check error that I can't figure out

This snippet works as expected.

```
  def combine(m: Map[Char, Int], tup: (Char, Int)): Map[Char,Int] = tup match {
    case (key: Char, value: Int) => m updated (key, m.getOrElse(key, 0) + value)
  }
```

This snippet gives a type mismatch error on `value`

```
  def combine(m: Map[Char, Int], tup: (Char, Int)): Map[Char,Int] = tup match {
    case (key: Char, value: Int) => m + (key -> m.getOrElse(key, 0) + value)
  }

 found   : Int
 required: String
           case (key: Char, value: Int) => m + (key -> m.getOrElse(key, 0) + value)
                                                                             ^
```

Now, the [docs on map](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/maps.html) say that `ms updated (k,v)` is equivalent to `ms + (k->v)` but that appears to not be the case.

Here's my setup:

```
SBT version 0.13.8
Scala version 2.11.8
Java SDK 1.8
IntlliJ IDEa
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key -> m.getOrElse(key, 0) + value` means, `(key->m.getOrElse(key, 0)) + value`. So, effectively, you are trying to add an `Int` to a tuple, no surprise, that does not work.

Try using parentheses:  `m + (key -> (m.getOrElse(key, 0) + value))`